# Facebook statuses requests sometimes returns empty

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I use the following methods to get status updates from multiple users.

```
public void getUserFeed(long userID, RequestListener listener) {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("uid", userID + "");
    params.putString("fields", "statuses");
    asyncFacebookRunner.request(FRIENDS, params, listener);
}

public void getFeedsForUsers(List<User> facebookUsersInFeed,
        final RequestListener listener) {
    for (final User user : facebookUsersInFeed) {
        getUserFeed(user.getId(), listener);
    }
}
```

Most of the time, this works fine. But every now and then, I get a response in which the data array is completely empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible you get a timeout?

Comment: Are you on a particularly slow network when it happens? Or are you always on the same network

Comment: I am always on the same network, should not be a problem..

Comment: I notice some `Async` calls. I once had an app that couldn't instantiate any new threads because the existing `AsyncTasks` were never being killed/finished, although they would run the entire code. I've never managed to fix it though.

Comment: That would make sense, since there are a LOT of Async calls being made throughout the application..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason is because that specific user has blocked 3rd party apps from accessing their data, therefore, when you try to fetch their info it will return empty.